# Creating JSON object from Typescript class

Tags: json, typescript

I have a class Person and after setting its properties, figuring out best way to convert that class to json object.

```
class Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

let person = new Person();
person.firstName = "FirstName";
person.lastName = "LastName";
```

If i do person.getJson() it should give json object as given below

```
{
  "firstName": "FirstName",
  "lastName": "LastName"
}
```

and incase lastName is not set then json object should only have firstName

```
{
  "firstName": "FirstName"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a `getJson()` method on class `Person`.
You can just call

```
JSON.stringify(person);
```

If you really want to put in your class...

```
class Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    getJson() {
        return JSON.stringify(this);
    }
}
```